# Get first variable value from a URL

Tags: php

Im trying to get the first variable from a url

```
callback/?Flag=action_one&message=1&result=success
```

I need to get the value in Flag and result
When I echo $_GET[‘result’] it prints the value but when I do $_GET[‘Flag’] it says

```
Notice: Undefined index: Flag
```

Can someone please tell me how can I get the value in Flag?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET)` say?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it has something to do with that `'/'` try the correct full url eg `callback/index.php?Flag=` or `callback.php?Flag=` whichever is appropriate